# how do I use first letters of my UITableview Sections and not the entire section label?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexing

So I'm using the below code to get the index listed for my table view...however it is return the entire section header which is not really what I want. I want to be able to return just a first letter to let people get quickly to the section of the table I need. I'm not sure how to implement this.

Thanks

[image: Index is using full names..]

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return keys
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like your keys are,

```
let keys = ["Stack","Swift","iOS","Xcode"];
```

now, make one another `array of String` just like,

```
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    var letter = [String]()
    for key in keys {
        letter.append("\(key.characters.first!)")
     }
     return letter
}
```

> **you have to do this things, bcz, you must have to return `[String]`**
>   **not** **`[Character]`**

### OR

be sure your keys have not same first character, if is that so,

```
var letters = [Character]()
letters = letters.sorted()
        letters = letters.reduce([], { (list, name) -> [Character] in
            if !list.contains(name) {
                return list + [name]
            }
            return list
        })



func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        var letter = [String]()
            for i in 0..<(letters.count){
                letter.append("\(letters[i])")
            }
            return letter
    }
```

**From above you get sorted keys as first character as well as not duplicated.**